# How to speed up Evolution

Tags: evolution, performance

I have a moderately big Inbox file (around 2.3Gb) and Evolution takes a lot to start (it takes over 2.5 mins until I can perform any action -read or compose mail, for instance-). During that time, the shole system becomes unresponsive, with high HD activity.

It becomes unresponsive when retrieving mail, too: it stalls for about 30 secs. Closing evolution can take yet another 1.5 minutes, also.

Is there any way I can speed things up?

---

**Last Edit:** *As I have checked that reducing my inbox file size (by means of moving old mail to an 'Archived Mail' folder) does the trick of speeding everything up, while keeping a copy of every mail at hand, my ultimate question is:*

**Is there any "auto-archive" feature or plug-in or script or anything for Evolution? I could do it "by hand" using saved searches and such, but it would be nice to have it automatically done (as it is in Outlook, for instance)**

---

**Previous Edit:**

*Answering comments:*

- Evolution retrieves POP mail from gmail and a personal postfix/courier mailserver
- I could change to any other mail client provided that A) migration is easy enough  B) Speed problems are likely to vanish with the new client and C) I can sync contacts and calendar with gmail
- I'm not experiencing high HDD activity problems with other apps, and swap is not (or at least should not be) a problem, since it's usually at 0% (I'll keep an eye on it, anyway)

*Other considerations:*

- I used to work with Outlook and it managed several 2 Gb files (one was actually the inbox, and three were "archive.pst" files, to which I never added more mails, except when Outlook auto-archived old ones). I even would like to add this pst files to Evolution, so that I can be able to search old mails, but A) I don't know how and B) I'm scared... If evolution can't handle properly a 2.3 Gb file, adding load would be a bad idea, I suppose.
- I guess things would speed up if I could "move" some old mail from my Inbox file to another one, but it should be readable and searchable. Anyway, I don't know if this can be done with Evolution, and, as stated, is just a guess.

Comment: Have you got the same problems with other HDD intensive applications? How much of you swap is used when running Evolution?

Comment: A solution that might be overkill is to get an SSD to increase read speed.

Comment: Evolution is naturally a little slow. Have you considered another email client, such as Thunderbird?

Comment: imap or pop? What email service?

Comment: @wojox: pop.... retrieving from gmail and also from personal mail server (postfix+courier)

Comment: @N.N.: No other HDD intensive applications that I can recall. Swap is not used unless I'm using Chorome (tens of tabs open) and a W7 VM.... (I have 8Gb RAM, so swap should not be a problem).... About the SSD... yes, it would be fine, but I'd rather fix it some other way. No budget available :(

Comment: @Warrioring64: I will if I can't fix this one... I'll ask for transition details if necessary....

Comment: @luri Have you tried putting the inbox file on another computer with Evolution to see if it's as slow?

Comment: Not really... actually, this is my "big" machine (8Gb RAM, AMD X6...) Ohers would be an old P5 and my laptop, whose specs are quite lower. Why do you think it could be specifically *this* computer?

Comment: @luri Might be a specific setting on that computer or driver related. Might help to nail the problem down by trying it on another computer.

Comment: I have.. same behaviour... When I open Evolution, the Inbox file is copied (obviously to the same location ~/.local/share/evolution/mail/local). The same happens when I receive mail. It does not seem to "append" anything to the file, but just plainly rewrite it all... The (partial) solution I'm trying right now is: A) Create a filter (search) to select old mails (let's say 2 years old) B) Move these mails to another folder (which means another file) which I imaginatively called OLDMAILS and C) Purge trash (as they're copied there, too when moved)... this way, the Inbox file gets thinner.

Comment: The funny thing is when I import (via pop) mails from Gmail, no matter if they are 'received' or 'sent' by me, it all goes to my Inbox, so it's actually a 'EverythingBox'.... Maybe I should move sent mail, too, to 'Sent mail' folder, reducing the load of work on the -actual- Inbox file

Answer (score 1):

Beware the .PST files are limited in size by design, i do not recommend using THAT big size into a single file. I use netcat for mail, when no Web avaliable.

Comment: Ok..... The question is... how do I split my Inbox file (it's important to recal that *I haven't added the big .pst files yet*, I'm just talking about my Evolution default Inbox file) in smaller chunks?